# How to update a profile attribute by link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update a `Profile` model attribute by using `link_to`. The `Profile` model have a `lang` column, and I want to change to `:en`.

I could find out that I should use `method: :put`.

```
<%= link_to t('english'), profile_path(profile: {lang: :en}), method: :put %>
```

But it's ends up with error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in StaticPages#home
Showing /Users/ironsand/dev/phrasebook/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #21 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles", :profile=>{:lang=>:en}} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I have this line in `routes.rb` to use the path:

```
resources :profiles, only: :update
```

How can I enable the function like this?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751869/link-to-update-without-form), but the case is a bit difference.

### Edit

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    return redirect_to root_path unless current_user # If user is not logged in, redirect to /
    if current_user.profile.update(profile_params) # Don't forget about validation for lang in Profile model
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
  private
  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:lang)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the profile somehow, that's why it asks for id. But you can update profile without id, you just need to improve update method:

```
def update
  return redirect_to root_path unless current_user # If user is not logged in, redirect to /

  if current_user.profile.update(profile_params) # Don't forget about validation for lang in Profile model
    redirect_to success_path
  else
    redirect_to error_path
  end
end

private

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:lang)
end
```

For route, try this:

```
resources :profiles, only: [] do
  collection do
    put :update
  end
end
```

or just:

```
put '/profiles' => 'profiles#update'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got a error `param is missing or the value is empty: profile` in the line ` params.require(:profile).permit(:lang)`.

Comment: Did you change the link? Check logs for this request and look for "Parameters: ..." If there is no `{ profile: { lang: :en }}`, but only `{lang: :en}`, then just remove this part: `.require(:profile)`

Comment: oh, that was my terrible mistake, and thanks I could do it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're updating a specific profile, you need to supply something that lets your controller know what profile you're updating.

As you can see from the error message generated, your controller can't identify which profile it is that you're asking to be updated. You need to supply the `id` of the profile in order to update it.

One way this could be achieved with `link_to` is as follows:

```
link_to t('english'), profile_path(id: @profile.id, lang: :en), method: :put
```

`lang` would then be available in your `update` action in `params[:lang]`.