# Rails: Update data via link_to (without view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to update the data without form.

Although there are similar questions, they don't work for me.

[Update field through link_to in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687085/update-field-through-link-to-in-rails)

[link_to update (without form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751869/link-to-update-without-form)

What I'd like to do is to delete data as followings;

For example, delete `name` and `address` when delete link is clicked.

```
id | name | address | ...
12 | aaa  | bbb     | ...
```

to

```
id | name | address | ...
12 |      |         | ...
```

Although I tried some, error was displayed.(such as `ActionController::RoutingError`)

**schema**

```
  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "address"
    ...
```

**model**

schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rooms, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
  ...
```

room.rb

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :rooms
  default_scope -> { order(day: :asc) }
  ...
```

**view**

I'd like to add the link in `schedules/_schedule.html.erb`
It has the followings;

```
  ...
  <% schedule.rooms.each do |room| %>
  ...
    <% if room.name.present? %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", rooms_path(room, room:{address: nil}) , method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
  ...
```

I also tried another code as below, but they don't work.

```
   <%= link_to "Delete", rooms_path(room:{address: nil}) , method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>

   <%= link_to "Delete", rooms_path(room) , method: :put, params: {address: nil}, data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
```

and so on.

**routes.rb**

```
...
  resources :schedules do
    resources :events
  end

  resources :schedules do
    resources :rooms
  end

  resources :rooms do
    resources :events
  end
...
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
...

def edit
  #nothing
end

def update
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  if @room.update(room_params)
    flash[:success] = "Room updated!"
    redirect_to itinerary_path(@room.itinerary) || current_user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  @room.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Room deleted"
  redirect_to schedule_path(@room.schedule) || current_user
end

private

  def room_params
    params.require(:room).permit(
      :id, :_destroy, :name, :address, :schedule_id, :day)
  end

...
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: post your routes..

Comment: Thank you for quick response, @Gokul M. I add routes at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `rooms_path` to `room_path`.

## Without params:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", room_path(room) , method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
```

## With params:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", room_path(room, room: {name: nil, address: nil}) , method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Gokul M. Although I tried your code, another  error is displayed. `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: room):`.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue I changed my answer you can just pass the `room` to `room_path`

Comment: Thank you for your update, @Gokul M. Although I tried both with and without params, they don't work. `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: room):` is displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Gokul M. I added the controller at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Where is the delete action?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Gokul M. I added the `destroy` in my controller. But I'm sorry if I mislead you. What I'd like to do is to erase the data in some columns such as `name` and `address`, although the link name is `Delete`. I don't want to delete the row. It's more to the edit than to the delete.

Comment: change `@Room.destroy` to `@room.destroy`If you want to just update the fields you can just link_to your update path with `name` and `address` params as `room: {name: null, address: null}`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Gokul M. I tried `<%= link_to "Delete", room_path(room: {name: null, address: null}), method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>`, the following error is displayed `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'null' for #<#<Class:xxx>):` It would be appreciated if you could show me how to apply to my code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Gokul M. It seems to work because the above error is not displayed. Although another error is displayed, it may be a different problem. Thank you for your time!